# Taylor expansion of Lagrangian

Tags: calculus

I'm a bit confused...

According to my knowledge a Taylor expansion is given by: $f(x+a)=f(a)+f'(a)*x=f(a)+x*df/dx$ (to first order approximation)...

Now according to Landau in a physics book (and i'm sure it's correct) he writes:

$L(v^2+2ve+e^2)=L(v^2)+dL/d(v^2)*2v*e$ to first order in powers of $e$. where $d$ in this context is the partial derivative... Now I tried using my expression for a Taylor expansion setting a=0 (maclaurin) and I get: $L(v^2+2ve)$ <--- neglectiing e^2 is: 
$$
L(v^2+2ve)= L(v^2)+e*L'(0) = L(v^2)+e*dL/de
$$ 
now $dL/de = (dL/du)(du/de)$ using the chain rule. By setting $u=v^2$ we get: $$L(v^2)+e*L'(0) = L(v^2)+e*dL/du*du/de=L(v^2)+e*dL/dv^2*du/de= L(v^2)+e*dL/dv^2*dv^2/de.$$ Now my question is quite simple: why is $dv^2/de=2v$? And how do you realise this? Is there any easier way to do this?

Comment: That is almost impossible to read :)

Comment: Sorry forgot Latex commandoes... been a while I wrote in Latex... hmm

Comment: [MathJax formatting](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation)

Comment: Start by using \$ \$...and put some space between your equations and divide all the text into paragraphs.

Comment: Related Phys.SE post by OP: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/241562/2451

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first bit is right, $$ L(v^2+2ve)\approx L(v^2)+e\left.\frac{dL}{de}\right|_{e=0}$$

However, $dL/de=dL/du \times du/de$ where $u=v^2+2ve$, so $dL/du=dL/d(v^2)$ and $du/de=2v$.

Comment: Thanks... I must have forgotten some notation... why is dL/du=dL/d(v2)?

Comment: Well, you need to compute the derivative of $L$ with respect to its argument, that's all. Since $v^2$ appears in the argument without any multiplication constant, we can use it for the derivative.

Comment: Aha thanks mate :)!

Comment: Question: "the argument" as you call it is it the independent variable? Cuz if it is then uhm? We set a=v^2 and hence the variable to e??

Comment: Thus I don't understand why dL/du= dL/d(v^2) when u=v^2+2ve... aka why is du=d(v^2)? Aka we treat v^2 as an constant and e as the variable not the other way around?

Comment: I think you are being confused by the notation in your book, which is indeed less than perfect. When the book writes $dL/d(v^2)$ it is implied that $e=0$, because the derivative is being taken at $e=0$.

Comment: So it's a Maclaurin series of f(x+a)=f(a)+f'(a)*x (to 1st. order) (approximation) of L(v^2+2ev) where v^2 is the variable or e is?

Comment: aka is  f(x+a)= L(v^2+2ev) where x=v^2 and a= 2ev or: x=2ev and a=v^2 or: x=e and a=v^2

Comment: Yeah it's indeed sloppy (in my mind) mathematically written meh

Comment: When you expand something to first order in $x$, then $x$ has to be small. In this case it can be $e$ or $2ev$, doesn't matter as long as you do it carefully. And the derivative is taken with respect to the other variable, in this case $v^2$. The book is not so bad :)

Comment: aha. So x=e and a=v^2 hence L(x+a)=L(e+v^2)=L(v^2)+e*L'(v^2) and e*L'(v^2) = e*2v*dL/d(v^2) because??? e is e but why is *L'(v^2)=2v*dL/d(v^2)... I know the book should be awesome (it's Landau after all heheh) I'm just very rusty I guess :S

Comment: No I'm sorry, I'm trying to work and answer this at the same time and I'm getting confused. The derivative is with respect to $x$ and computed at $x=0$, and it can be computed by using the chain rule so you end up taking the derivative of $L$ with respect to its argument, and then setting $x=0$. I am pretty sure you are now able to understand this. Cheers

Comment: ... Shouldn't we devide with respect to the independent variable which we here chose to be e? aka: why isn't L'(v^2)= dL/de|e=v^2

Comment: aha thanks mate :)